# How to override a method by using conditional

Tags: python, oop

I will show you my script and then I explain what I want to do

```
class Animal(object):
    def __init__(self,name=None):
        self.name=name
        if name=="dog":
            object=Dog()
        if name=="cat":
            object=Cat()
    def execute(self):
        print("I am animal")

class Dog:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def execute(self):
        print("I am a dog")

class Cat:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def execute(self):
        print("I am a cat")


if __name__ =="__main__":
    instanceAnimal=Animal("cat") # I would like to get "I am a cat" but I got "I am animal"
    instanceAnimal.execute()
```

I know it is not the good way to inherent but I have an use case and I want to instantiate an instance Animal and by given a name in the input this class will call the appropriate execute.

Hope my example is clear

Comment: Why not make a (factory) function that returns the appropriate object instead?

Comment: you're calling the `execute` function from the `Animal` class, so you can't return anything other than "I am animal". Your `Cat` object isn't actually connected to the `Animal` class either, maybe `self.species = Cat()` I would say the `print` functions should be a `__str__` as well. I agree a factory function is probably a better approach, assuming you can't use inheritance for some substantive reason

Comment: Thank you, I will try to use factory function also but @DeepSpace solution worked for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Although inheritance is the best solution here the OP specifically asks for another solution**

`object = Dog()` or `object = Cat()` does not do anything useful. It assigns a `Dog` or `Cat` instance to local variable `object` and that's about it. It does not bind it to anything.

You will have to keep a reference to it in `Animal` and bind `Animal.execute` to the appropriate `execute` method.

Also, you can use a dictionary to make the initialization a bit more concise:

```
class Dog:
    def execute(self):
        print("I am a dog")

class Cat:
    def execute(self):
        print("I am a cat")

class Animal(object):
    names_to_classes = {'dog': Dog, 'cat': Cat}

    def __init__(self, name=None):
        self.name = name
        try:
            self.object = self.names_to_classes[name]()
        except KeyError:
            raise TypeError('name must be either "dog" or "cat"')

    def execute(self):
        self.object.execute()


instanceAnimal = Animal("cat")
instanceAnimal.execute()
instanceAnimal = Animal("dog")
instanceAnimal.execute()
instanceAnimal = Animal("penguin")
instanceAnimal.execute()
```

outputs

```
I am a cat
I am a dog
TypeError: name must be either "dog" or "cat"
```

The downside of this approach is that `Dog.__init__` and `Cat.__init__` are expected to accept the same arguments.

Answer (score 2):

A clean solution using a metaclass and inheritance:

```
class AnimalType(type):
    _classes = {}

    def __init__(cls, name, attribs, bases):
        super(AnimalType, cls).__init__(name, attribs, bases)
        cls._classes[name.lower()] = cls


class Animal(object):
    __metaclass__ = AnimalType

    def __new__(cls, name=None):
        newcls = type(cls)._classes.get(name, Animal)
        return object.__new__(newcls, name)

    def __init__(self, name=None):
        self.name = name

    def execute(self):
        print("I am animal")


class Dog(Animal):
    def execute(self):
        print("I am a dog")


class Cat(Animal):
    def execute(self):
        print("I am a cat")
```

And if you DONT want inheritance at all, just use a factory function:

```
class Animal(object):
    def execute(self):
        print("I am animal")

class Dog:
    def execute(self):
        print("I am a dog")

class Cat:
    def execute(self):
        print("I am a cat")


_clsmap = {
   "animal": Animal,
   "dog": Dog,
   "cat": Cat
   }

def make_animal(name):
    return _clsmap.get(name, Animal)()
```

Comment: Thank you @bruno desthuilliers ^^

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can achieve what you want:

```
class Animal(object):
    def __init__(self, name=None):
        if name == 'cat':
            self._object = Cat()
        elif name == 'dog':
            self._object = Dog()
        else:
            self._object = None

    def execute(self):
        if self._object is not None:
            self._object.execute()
        else:
            print("I am animal")
```